# missing compilation references in Razor pages after adding model

Tags: c#, razor, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am creating a .NET Core web app using framework 4.6.2. I built my first view, testing throughout, until I added my view model and the page now errors out whenever I navigate to it. The errors are shown below. The ViewModel has all of the referenced properties on it. I don't even have a project.json given it's a brand new project on VS17.

[image: screenshot showing referenced errors including Type Expected, type or namespace TModel could not be found, and several instances of "View Model does not contain a definition for property"]

Comment: Could you add some code? You might have referenced the model incorrectly, or not have the model's namespace in the view usings.

Comment: I figured it out pretty quickly after retracing my steps, see answer below c:

Answer (score 0):

This will happen if the properties you're using on your view model are not marked `public`. In my case, I had them marked `internal` and so was getting this error.